# Inheritance With Blazor Component Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to implement a simple heirarchy for the classes behind my blazor pages, but for some reason I keep getting a build error.

What I've implemented is a simple way to update breadcrumbs from mudblazor using inheritance using an interface `IBreadCrumbEnabled`

```cs
namespace BlazorConversionProject.Areas
{
    public interface IBreadCrumbEnabled
    {
        void UpdateBreadcrumbs();
    }
}
```

I've made a base class called `BaseAdminComponent.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using MudBlazor;

namespace BlazorConversionProject.Areas
{
    public class BaseAdminComponent : ComponentBase, IBreadCrumbEnabled
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public List<BreadcrumbItem> Crumbs { get; set; }

        public void UpdateBreadcrumbs()
        {
            Crumbs.Add(new BreadcrumbItem("Admin", null));
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is implemented by whatever page I'm using

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using MudBlazor;

namespace BlazorConversionProject.Areas.Facilities
{
    public partial class FacilitiesView : BaseAdminComponent
    {
        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to build this, I get:

```
Error   CS0115  'FacilitiesView.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable method found to override
```

If `FacilitiesView` inherits from `ComponentBase` directly, or doesn't inherit from anything at all, then the error goes away, but if I try to inherit from any other class in `FacilitiesView` everything breaks, and I just don't understand why I can't have another class inherit from `ComponentBase` and then inherit from that for my component.

I checked and can confirm that `ComponentBase` is not sealed, so it makes no sense why there is no suitable method to override.

Comment: I don't see where you are inheriting from `ComponentBase`. Perhaps you forgot to have `BaseAdminComponent` do that?

Comment: Have you included `@inherits BaseAdminComponent` in your `FacilitiesView.razor` file?

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, `BaseAdminComponent` should inherit from `ComponentBase`

Comment: @AstridE. I have not included any of that in the razor file

Comment: What happens if you do?

Comment: @AstridE. Same error

Comment: Interesting, that sorted it for me when I reproduced the scenario. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Okay, I went back and tried it again, and it does actually work, I was just missing a couple of things, if you make that an answer, I will accept it

Comment: NP. the problem was almost certainly in the code your aren't showing us  Don't worry, that pretty normal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce this issue, I got an additional error:

> **Error CS0263** Partial declarations of 'FacilitiesView' must not specify different base classes

The reason this error occurred was that I had *only* specified the inheritance in `FacilitiesView.razor.cs`.

I solved it by specifying the inheritance in `FacilitiesView.razor` as well:

**FacilitiesView.razor.cs:**

```
public partial class FacilitiesView : BaseAdminComponent
```

**FacilitiesView.razor:**

```
@inherits BaseAdminComponent
```

Comment: I found it so strange that I have to both inherit in the class file, as well as in the razor file, that seems so strange

Comment: It is not strange at all. The base component is split into a razor and cs file. So you have to inherit from both as well.

Comment: +1.  I believe it's because the class is declared `partial`, so both "parts" (the .razor/.cs files) must inherit from the same base.

Comment: @EvilDr I like your theory. I have tried to find documentation to support this, but to no avail.